# PHP array reference inconsistency

Tags: php

I have an HTML form that posts fields with names like thing$0 and thing$1, which I want to map to global PHP variables with names like $gvar[0]->thing and $gvar[1]->thing. I parse the field names to obtain 'thing' and subscript values 0 and 1. I wanted a PHP function that would return a reference to $gvar. [The object names are more complicated than just $gvar -- I'm greatly simplifying the complete problem.]

Here are two versions of a function:

```
function testfunc1($junk)
    {
    global $gvar1;
    $obj = &$gvar1;
    $obj[0] = new stdClass;
    $obj[0]->foo = $junk;
    return $obj;
    }

function testfunc2($junk)
    {
    global $gvar2;
    $obj = &$gvar2;
    $obj[0] = new stdClass;
    $obj[0]->foo = $junk;
    $obj[1] = new stdClass;
    return $obj;
    }

function test($parms)
    {                       // session::test
    global $gvar1, $gvar2;

    $obj1 = $this->testfunc1(42);
    $obj1[1] = new stdClass;
    $obj1[1]->foo = 43;
    // At this point: $gvar1 is [1] with [0]->foo === 42
    // $obj1 is [2] with [0]->foo === 42, [1]->foo === 43

    $obj2 = $this->testfunc2(42);
    $obj2[1]->foo = 43;
    // At this point: $gvar2 AND $obj2 are [2] with [0]->foo === 42, [1]->foo === 43
    return 666;    
    }                       // session::test
```

Both versions create the [0] element the target array. The first version leaves it to the caller to create the [1] element. The second version creates both array elements. Coming from a C++ background, it seems to me that both versions should produce identical results, but they don't. It appears that PHP doesn't let you return a reference to an array from a function -- you can only return a copy of an array whose elements are identical to the elements seen inside the function.

Is there a way to avoid having the function create the array elements past [0], so that the calling function can use the names of POSTed fields thing$1, thing$2, … to create as many $gvar[1], $gvar[2], ... elements as needed?

Comment: How have you set the variables `$gvar`? And why do you have `thing$0` as form names instead of array expressions like `thing[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from the different treatment of types when passing to functions or returning from them. If you return null, bool, int or float, they are effectively copied. If they are objects like e.g. stdClass, what you pass to the function behaves like a C++ reference, so both inside the function and outside you refer to the same object. The unexpected part (at least to me, who also has a C++ background) is the fact that arrays are not treated as objects. So, when you return an array, it is copied and if it contains an object, the copy has an element that refers to the same object.

Note: I wrote "effectively copied" for a reason. I'm not sure about the PHP internals, but it's possible that for the simple types like bool, there is no way to modify them. The only thing you can do then is to assign a different instance to a variable. Further, it's possible that PHP uses "copy on write" to avoid the copying overhead. Both are implementation details that don't effect the semantic.

Now, concerning your goal, it seems odd that your functions both write to globals and return those globals. I'd pick either of the two, preferably the one that doesn't use globals. Effectively, you take the HTTP request parameters and convert them into a different representation. For that, I'd use a single function which does just that and returns the result. Since it's a pure function, it could also be unit-tested much easier.

Comment: The oddity is a result of my having reduced the problem to its absolute essentials. In reality, my object names are potentially long series of dot-separated components where each component names a subject. An example target might be $_SESSION['USERINFO']['alldata']->ExpenseInfo->OtherExpenses[0]->what, which is persisted in a database. This target corresponds to a value on a form that delivers a field SaveAs="ExpenseInfo.OtherExpenses[]" and another field named what$0. As you can see the value destined to be the subscript on OtherExpenses comes from another field entirely.